# How to populate a CSV column by column in a loop with Python?

Tags: python, loops, csv

### Solved:  A friend of mine helped me add in code that takes the csv files which get outputted and combines them into a single new file.  I will add the code in after the weekend in case anyone else with a similar issue wants to see it in the future!

Let me start by sharing my existing, working code.  This code takes some raw data from a csv file and generates new csv files from it.  The data consists of two columns, one representing voltage and one representing current.  If the voltage value is not changing, the current values are sent to a new csv file whose name reflects the constant voltage.  Once a new stable voltage is reached, another csv is made for that voltage and so on.  Here it is:

```
for x in range(1,6):
    input=open('signalnoise(%d).csv' %x,"r") # Opens raw data as readable
    v1 = 0
    first = True
    for row in csv.reader(input,delimiter='\t'):
            v2 = row[0]
            if v1==v2:
                voltage=float(v1)*1000
                if first:
                    print("Writing spectra file for " +str(voltage) + "mV")
                    first = False
                output=open('noisespectra(%d)' %x +str(voltage)+'mV.csv',"a")
                current = [row[1]]
                writer=csv.writer(output,delimiter='\t')
                writer.writerow(current)
            else:
                v1 = row[0]
                first = True
```

One note, for some reason the print command doesn't seem to go off until the entire script is done running but it prints the correct thing.  This could just be my computer hanging while the script runs.

I would like to change this so that instead of having a bunch of files, I just have one output file with multiple columns.  Each column would have its first entry be the voltage value followed by all the currents recorded for that voltage.  Here is my idea so far but I'm stuck:

```
for x in range(1,6):
    input=open('signalnoise(%d).csv' %x,"r") # Opens raw data as readable
    v1 = 0
    first = True
    for row in csv.reader(input,delimiter='\t'):
            v2 = row[0]
            if v1==v2:
                voltage=float(v1)*1000
                if first:
                    column = ['voltage']
                    print("Writing spectra file for " +str(voltage) + "mV")
                    first = False
                column=column+[row[1]] # Adds the current onto the column
                saved = True # Means that a column is being saved

             elif saved: # This is executed if there is a column waiting to be appended and the voltage has changed
#I get stuck here...
```

At this point I think I need to somehow use item.append() like the example [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/912694-how-use-python-add-column-csv-file) but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it.  Then I would set saved = False and v1 = row[0] and have the same else statement as the original working code so that on the next iteration things would proceed as desired.

Here is some simple sample data to work with (although mine is actually tab delimited):

```
.1, 1
.2, 2
.2, 2
.2, 2.1
.2, 2
.3, 3
.4, 4
.5, 5.1
.5, 5.2
.5, 5
.5, 5.1
```

My working code would take this and give me two files named 'noisespectra(#)200.0mV.csv' and 'noisespectra(#)500.0mV.csv' which are single columns '2,2,2.1,2' and '5.1,5.2,5,5.1' respectively.  I would like code which makes a single file named 'noisespectra(#).csv' which is two columns, '200.0mV,2,2,2.1,2' and '500.0mV,5.1,5.2,5,5.1'.  In general, a particular voltage will not have the same number of currents and I think this could be a potential problem in using the item.append() technique, particularly if the first voltage has fewer corresponding currents than future voltages.

Feel free to disregard the 'for x in range()'; I am looping through files with similar names but that's not important for my problem.

I greatly appreciate any help anyone can give me!  If there are any questions, I will try to address them as quickly as I can.

Comment: Can you distill this question? There is way too much information to get useful answers. I read through the whole thing but its tough to infer exactly what you need.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the two sets of values in two lists, then do ...

```
combined = map(None, list_1, list_2)
```

And then output the combined list to csv.